# Asp.Net pass data from code-behind to code-infront?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this in my code behind on my Asp.Net page

```
Public Class display
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Property pID As String
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If (Request.QueryString("id") = "") Then
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
        Else
            pID = Request.QueryString("id")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now, I want to get the ID to influence items in the code infront when the page loads, so i added this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# pID %>'></asp:Label>
```

as a test object. when ran 'Label1' is just a blank span. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `<%# pID %>`, Just use

```
 Label1.Text = pID
```

As `Label1` is a server control and is accessible in page load.

Change your code as

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Request.QueryString("id") = "") Then
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
    Else
        pID = Request.QueryString("id")
        Label1.Text = pID
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT:

I would suggest you to use [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 <asp:LinkButton OnClick="LinkButton_Click" />
```

CS Code

```
  Sub LinkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
     Response.Redirect(piccom.displayLink(pID))
  End Sub
```

Comment: Ah yes... i should off gone more in depth. Later on in the code its used for changing the `href` of `<a></a>` tags, in this sort of fashion. `<a href="<%#piccom.displayLink(pID)%>" class="genLink">`, where that function returns a string based off the pID given. but its not passing the pID across.

Comment: @JamesTrotter, What is `piccom.displayLink`? Can you provide its code? so that better solution be acheived

Comment: its not really important, all it does is return a string, it works perfectly in other areas of the site, the problem is pID is not getting passed.

Comment: @JamesTrotter, I have updated answer. I would suggest you to use `LinkButton` or `HyperLink ` as suggested bu meda

Comment: @James Trotter its not working because you have to write it like that `<= pID>` and make sure that property is public but spatal got the better approach you want to keep your markup clean and work in the behind file

Comment: Thankyou, im new to .net development and never realised there was a link button, should of checked! beginners mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Keep things simple and organized like @saptal is suggesting.

```
pID = Request.QueryString("id")
Label1.Text = pID
```

If you need an anchor control you can use the HyperLink control like this on your markup:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID ="genHyperLink" CssClass="genLink" runat="server" />
```

code behind:

```
genHyperLink.NavigateUrl = piccom.displayLink(pID)
```